# How can i customize the dafault behavior of jackson when returning a ResponseEntity<> with PagedResources<>?

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-data, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

Im using spring boot on my proyect. Basically, all i want is to include inline entities in a response of a GET method while still using the advantages of spring-hateoas (_embedded and links).

Having this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_specialty", schema = "public", catalog = "icorelab")
public class SubSpecialty {
private Integer id;
private String name;
private Boolean active;
private Date createdAt;
private Date deletedAt;
private Specialty specialty;
private String description;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "specialty_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
public Specialty getSpecialtyBySpecialtyId() {
    return specialty;
}
```

I set up repository with PagingAndSorting capabilities, also it extends CustomRepository to provide custom methods. This repository uses a projection so an iternal entity gets serialized as mentioned here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.excerpts

```
 @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "sub_specialties", path =    "sub_specialties",
    excerptProjection = InlineSpecialty.class)
 public interface SubSpecialtyRepository extends    PagingAndSortingRepository<SubSpecialty, Integer>,SubSpecialtyRepositoryCustom {
```

The in a controller, i return the response by using Page and PageResourcesAssembler

```
Page<SubSpecialty> page =  subSpecialtyRepository.filter(name,description,active,specialty,limit,offset,pageable.getSort());
    PagedResources<SubSpecialty> pagedResources = pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(page,subSpecialtyResourceAssembler);


    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/sub_specialties/filter", offset, limit);
    ResponseEntity<?> response = new ResponseEntity<>(pagedResources, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
```

The problem is that the message does not include Specialty info, just the link

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "sub_specialties": [
            {
                "id": 107,
                "name": "PHARMACOLOGY",
                "active": false,
                "createdAt": "2017-09-30",
                "deletedAt": null,
                "description": null,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/sub_specialties/107{?projection}",
                        "templated": true
                    },
                    "subSpecialty": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/sub_specialties/107{?projection}",
                        "templated": true
                    },
                    "specialty": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/specialties/16"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 104,
                "name": "PHARMACOLOGY",
                "active": false,
                "createdAt": "2017-09-30",
                "deletedAt": null,
                "description": null,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/sub_specialties/104{?projection}",
                        "templated": true
                    },
                    "subSpecialty": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/sub_specialties/104{?projection}",
                        "templated": true
                    },
                    "specialty": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/specialties/16"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/sub_specialties/filter?page=0&size=20"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 2,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve this? I thought i could use an annotation on the entity domain class or a custom jackson serializer.The Specialty entity is included in the response, however is not included in the message that receives the client. I suppose there is some default configuration for jackson that detects a repository of type Specialty, and the just includes the link in the response.